# Login using PDO can't fetch data from MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem in my code it's login with any username and password without verify it from the database more explain below
I have 2 tables one for usernames and one for passwords, I trying to make my code like this
users table it's have: id, username, phone, email
password table it's have: id, userid, password

every password connected with id of the user by user_id field

I want my code work like this 
if username, email or phone in one row equal to the password have the same user_id the same as in the row make login

Example
users table: 1, eddy, edd@example.com, 4493838
passwords table: 1, 1(please note: it's user id from users table), alfa

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";$username = "username";$password = "password";$dbname = "myDBPDO";
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{?>

Welcome <? echo $_SESSION['users_id'] ?>
<?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['various-login']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
// PDO   
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Database
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id as users_id, username, email, phone FROM users"); 
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id as passwords_id, user_id, password FROM passwords"); 
$stmt->execute();

$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$various_login= $_POST['various-login'] == $userRow['email'] or $userRow['phone'];
$user_and_password = $userRow['users_id'] === $userRow['user_id'];  
$password = $_POST['password'] == $user_and_password;    

if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{

    $email = $userRow['email'];
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

    echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
    echo $email;
} 
else
{
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
}}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
} else {?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Email/Phone: <input type="text" name="various-login" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
<br><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['NEXT']; ?>">  
</form> 
<?php}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this : (Not secure for SQLi)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";$username = "username";$password = "password";$dbname = "myDBPDO";
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
    echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['Username'];
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['various-login']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{  
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Database
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, phone FROM users WHERE lower(username) = '".strtolower($_POST['various-login'])."' OR lower(email) = '".strtolower($_POST['various-login'])."' OR phone = '".strtolower($_POST['various-login'])."'"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $userdata = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($userdata["id"]))
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, password FROM passwords WHERE user_id = '".$userdata["id"]."' AND password = '".$_POST["password"]."'"); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $password_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($password_data["id"]))
            {
                $_SESSION['users_id'] = $userdata["id"]
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $userdata["username"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata["email"];
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
                echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
                echo $email;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                echo "<p>Sorry, your account password is not valid. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
} else {?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Email/Phone: 
    <input type="text" name="various-login" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
    <br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['NEXT']; ?>">  
</form> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Amin.MasterkinG thanks for help, it's all the time show error Sorry, your account could not be found. Please click here to try again.

Comment: sorry the same problem

Comment: Your passwords is not encrypted? It's should be work ! Your data is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using a join so it's 1 SQL statement, as well as a sanitizing and validating your input.

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users 
JOIN passwords ON passwords.user_id = users.id
WHERE (users.email = :email
OR users.phone = :phone)
AND passwords.password = :password
```

Here's the link to the documentation on prepared statements. I suggest you re-read that to understand why your existing code won't work (hint: you're selecting all records). http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

1. Create your PDO Connection
2. Create your SQL
3. Bind your parameters
4. Execute the query
5. If you have a row, you found the user.

I'm sure you're already aware of the issues with using plain text passwords, and have assumed this is an assignment and not something used in production.